# Two variable polynomial whose image is $\mathbb R^+\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: polynomials

Polynomial $P(x,y)$ takes only positive values for all x,y . Can it take all the positive values?

My thoughts : This is quite a strange one. I tried proving this by contradiction but I got nowhere fast.

Comment: Strict positiveness ?

Answer (score 8):

$$f(x,y)=x^2+(xy-1)^2$$ is the standard answer.

Comment: How does this address the question ?

Comment: @Yves, perfectly. It takes on all, and only, positive values.

Comment: You are right, shame on me :(

Answer (score 0):

Take $P(x,y)=x^2+y^2+3$ for example and try to find $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)=1$.

Comment: Actually you just found an example. In order to prove this you must work with an abstract polynomial not with a particular one

Comment: Alternatively, you must find a particular one that takes on all, and only, positive values.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question. But for me the question is : $P(x,y)>0$ for all $x,y$ implies $P(\mathbb{R}^2) = (0,+\infty)$. Consequently, my example answers the question.

Comment: I think the question is whether there *exists* a polynomial with range --- it's rather too easy to find a polynomial that *doesn't* have that range, isn't it?